# Grammatical error in consent banner

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, user-interface, grammar

I found a grammatical error in the consent banner (the banner at the bottom): "understand" should be changed to "understood".

So the banner content would become:

> By using our site, you acknowledge that you have read and understood our Cookie Policy, Privacy Policy, and our Terms of Service.

[image: Screenshot showing the consent banner]

Comment: Both are grammatically correct actually.

Answer (score 14):

"Understand" is present tense and implies an ongoing understanding in an agreement.

> I understand what you are saying.

"Understood" is past tense and acknowledges that you understood, but could be interpreted to mean that you may not understand in the future.

> I understood what you were saying.

While grammatically they are both valid options, from a legal standpoint "understand" is the *more* correct option.

Answer (score 6):

To address the reason this probably *appeared* ungrammatical, note that it would be a mistake to write:

> that you have read and you have understand

These wordings, which are similar in meaning to the wording you have proposed--"that you have read and understood"--are grammatical:

> that you have read and you have understood

> that you have read and you understood

But as [RageFoxx points out](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/344454/185080), that's not quite the *desired* meaning.

This wording has the desired meaning and is grammatical:

> that you have read and you understand

The existing wording--"that you have read and understand"--has that as its intended reading. *It is likewise grammatical*, because it can be read that way. (Strictly speaking, it must be read that way, since the other possible reading--"have understand"--doesn't make sense.)